# Fitnesse Slim: How to concatenate symbol

Tags: concatenation, symbols, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

How would one concatenate a symbol with text on either side? 
For example:

- Prefix: `"GAR_"`
- Variable: `$todayDate`
- Suffix: `"_1"`

`GAR_$todayDate_1`

Which would evaluate to:
`GAR_07202012_1`

When running the test in fitnesse, it seems as though the concatenation is working (`GAR_$todayDate->[07202012]_1`).  However, I am passing this value as a parameter to visual studio and I instead end up with the following text: `GAR_$todayDate_1`.

When I remove the suffix or put a space between `$todayDate` and `"_1"`, everything works as expected.

Any help would be appreciated.

Things I have tried:

- `GAR_!-$todayDate-!_1`
- `GAR_$todayDate!-_1-!`
- `GAR_$todayDate${SUFFIX}` - static variable defined

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am stuck with the same problem currently.
The only way I found was to:

1. create a `StringSupport` class with a `String concatenate(String s1, String s2)` method
2. `import` the package of that class in your FitNesse test
3. put `StringSupport` in the available libraries in your FitNesse test with the `Library` table
4. in your `Script`, you can now do: `|$result=|concatenate;|$s1|$s2|`

To fit your exact use case, you just have to do the same concatenate() with 3 strings instead of just one.

Comment: it will be great if wiki supports string concatenate like shell.