# FitNesse FIT concat String with Symbol and pass it as a parameter to method (in Java)

Tags: variables, symbols, fitnesse

Does FitNesse with Fit (not Slim) support something like?

```
...
| mySymbol=myMethod | |
...

!define myVariable {some text mySymbol= more text}
```

So that I can late use myVariable like

```
| anotherMethod | ${myVariable} |
```

as a parameter of another method.

My current solution is similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11686585/6685089

Is there a build in syntax in Fit to such a scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't combine Fit symbols with Wiki variables.  Wiki variables are evaluated by the Wiki engine when the page is rendered as HTML.  Fit symbols are evaluated when the HTML is parsed and executed by the test engine.